# MongoDB Trigger Match Expression suspends trigger after using $or operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to setup a trigger which should trigger only if field changes to any one of the value ['LIVE','OFFINE','DRAFT'].

To achive above functionality I used below Match Trigger

```
{
"updateDescription.updatedFields": {
"$or": [
 {"state":"LIVE"},
 {"state":"OFFLINE"},
 {"state":"DRAFT"},
]
}
}
```

When I save my trigger with above expression it saves successfully and after some time it suspends my trigger with **Unknown operator $or** error.

Comment: Can you try `{"updateDescription.updatedFields.state": {"$in": ["LIVE","OFFINE","DRAFT"]}}`?

Comment: @ray your solution is working. But why $or operator is not working? I am curious

Comment: check out `OR verses IN` https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#-or-versus--in

Comment: Hey @Naveen thanks for sharing doc link, I read it. but still it is not clear to me. Why $or is causing error?

Comment: @FaisalAhmed interestingly, I found no example of using `$or` (or other `$expr`) in MongoDB trigger on the internet, not even in the [official code example](https://github.com/mongodb/atlas-app-services-examples/tree/main/triggers-examples). I guess it might be not supported as of now.

Comment: Yes! It seems like it is not supported. Hope we will have something on docs in future.